# Redirect user to dashboard after successful login but still maintain laravel default error messages if an error occurs during login

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to redirect users to their dashboard after successful login and if credentials doesn't exists or match the database records it should return laravel's default error messages.

It redirects to dashboard view if successful, but when an errors occurs, it doesn't redirect me back to the login, instead it shows a blank page.

below is my code

```
  public function login(Request $request)
{

    $message = array(
        'required.email'    =>  'This is required',
        'required.password' =>  'This is required',
    );
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'password'  =>  'required|min:8',
    ]);

    $email = $request->email;
    $pass = $request->password;

    if (Auth::guard('guest')->attempt([
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $pass
    ], $request->get('remember'))) {

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    } else {
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should suffice your need

```
return redirect('dashboard')->withErrors('Something went wrong!');
```

Comment: Yea but i do what it to have laravel's default errors, rather than defining my own errors

Comment: you can use  ->getErrors() or ->errors() for the same

Comment: I get an this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::errors()` and `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::getErrors()`

Comment: they have different applications for validators you can use $validator->errors(),
if you are using models to save data and want to get validation error from models you can use getErrors from models, and so